# Cannot install cordova barcode scanner plugin: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

i'm trying to install this plugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner but the following error shows up:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\guadha.peralta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\serve.js:9:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: show your code also

Comment: Which node.js version you use?

Comment: @lin it's v0.12.2

Comment: Update your node and you should be fine.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal i typed the following in the command line : phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "arrow function" `=>` are ES6 functions. Update node to minimum v4.4.5 which starts supporting ES6. On windows you must have installed the latest version of node, which supports that type of function.

**Update node on Windows**

- Run PowerShell as Administrator and execute the following command:

`npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade`

Comment: @SydnieS https://nodejs.org/en/download/ just reinstall. Dont forget to reboot after install.

Comment: @SydnieS Any feedback or suggestions?

Comment: thanks. i tried to run npm update -g but it gives me the following error:    npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: phonegap@6.4.4
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=4.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.7.4","node":"0.12.2"}

Comment: @SydnieS Check your output: Node `0.12.2` - you still need to update your node version. Check my update answer.

Comment: how can i update nodejs via command line? i dont have admin access to run the msi